# Parametric Bootstrap Capture Recapture

Tags: ecology, population-biology, statistics

I am using the (one sample) capture recapture for estimating hidden human population. One sample method uses purely frequencies of capture to estimate population. One of my colleague suggested parametric bootstrapping method to assess the variability of the population size estimate. I tried to research online a little about this parametric bootstrap method but I just still don't understand how it is performed. I know bootstrapping is basically resampling data with replacement and then calculating the variance of it. However how do I perform parametric bootstrapping (I assume the frequencies of capture follows Poisson Distribution) on capture recapture data? Do we treat the frequencies as datas, i.e. so if f(1)=100 and f(2)=9, our data has 100x 1 and 9x 2 and then resampling this? Is probability of daily capture the parameter $\lambda$ in Poisson distribution?

I guess what I am trying to ask is, how do you perform the sampling bit of a parametric bootstrap [in capture recapture]?

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say "[your method] uses purely frequencies of capture". Is there any 'recapturing' going on?

Comment: @CactusWoman So unlike the normal capture recapture where they have discrete timings and capture history, my capture recapture is a continuous model (since only 1 individual can be captured at a time) and only frequencies of encountering individuals are noted. So the only data I have f(1), frequency of capturing individual once, f(2), ... Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research and I think it works like that:

1. Collect a dataset of $n$ observations.
2. Fit a parametric model to your data. If you want to model the recaptures, I would suggest a Poisson-GLM. You can also estimate the parameter directly from your data and simply parametrize a Poisson distribution. However, this approach would not model the random variation in your data.
3. Use the fitted model to draw a sample of size $n$
4. Calculate your desired metric based on the sample. I guess in your case this would be human population size (calculated as ${N} = \frac{nM}{m}$?)
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 many times (1000+)
6. There you go! Now you can easily assess the variability in population size based on the estimates from your bootstrap samples.

Comment: Im confused with step 2, I thought for estimating parameter from the bootstrap sample we use the same method we use for the original data?

Comment: I was referring to the parameter $\lambda$ of a Poisson distribution. You can estimate lambda based on your data using maximum likelihood. Some function to do this should be included in every serious statistical package. So what 2 says: Build a model from your data (a glm or a parametrized Poisson distribution) and use this model in steps 3 and 4 to for bootstrapping.